# Get the Checked Id of the checkBox React

Tags: reactjs

all I have static check boxes in which I want to capture the selected seat numbers into an array. Following is the code

```
<ul className="st_eco_second_row">
                    <li> <span>Pay Rs.790.00</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="c8" name="cb" />
                    <label htmlFor="c8" />
                    </li>
                    <li className="seat_disable">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="c9" name="cb" />
                    <label htmlFor="c9" />
                    </li>
                    <li className="seat_disable">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="c10" name="cb" />
                    <label htmlFor="c10" />
                    </li>
    </ul>
```

[image: seats]

```
const handleOnChange = (e) => {
        let isChecked = e.target.checked;
        seats.push(e.target.id)
        if(isChecked){
            alert(seats);
        }
    console.log(seats)
}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise? I cant' see the seat numbers in your code. Why are you using ul?

Comment: please always provice code as text, not as image

Comment: @IgorGonak understood ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event.target.id to get the ID of clicked checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c6" name="c6"
                    checked={seatChecked["c6"]} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>


handleChange(e) {
  let isChecked = e.target.checked;
  if(isChecked){
     alert(e.target.id);
  }
  else{
    
   this.setState({seats: this.state.seats.filter(function(value) { 
             return value !== e.target.value 
             })
   });


  }
}
```

Comment: i have added the checked value to an array, is it possible to remove the value if checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: yes, you can remove it.

Comment: how to remove it?

Comment: can you put this as a functional component?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define some suitable state - either an object or an array. Then use checked and onChange to sync to this state:

```
 const initialState = {
    c1: false,
    c2: false,
    c3: false,
    c4: false,
    c5: false
  };
  const [selectedSeats, setSelectedSeats] = useState(initialState);
  const toggleSeat = (id) =>
    setSelectedSeats((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, [id]: !prev[id] };
    });
```

...

```
<input
    checked={selectedSeats.c1}
    type="checkbox"
    id="c1"
    name="seats"
    onChange={() => toggleSeat("c1")}
  />
 <label htmlFor="c1">c1</label>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-glade-6kig84

Of course you can create your checkboxes dynamically from an object or array. I copy pasted them for the sake of simplicity.